# Kubernetes internal redirects

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to implement a custom load balancer based on headless service. What I found working (for now) was the following setup:

1. worker
2. worker-service
3. load-balancer
4. load-balancer-service
5. headless-service

Client calls load balancer which calls headless service to check the available pods. Load balancer picks one pod and calls it.

This is fine, but it means that the LB would be a proxy as well, which I'd like to avoid. I've tried **redirect** but then the ip:port address is returned back to the client - and the pod is obviously not accessible outside from cluster (I've tried simple ingress as well).

Do you Folks have any hints & tips & tricks how to do such thing?

Thanks!
Mateusz

Comment: Can you try Kubernetes service discovery along with DNS-based load balancing. Keep headless service it has DNS based service discovery for worker pods. In headless service this automatically setup DNS record for each pod. These DNS records are used to load balance requests across all available pods. You can resolve headless service DNS name to get the list of IP addresses of your pods. Use external load balancer to distribute incoming traffic across the replicas of your headless service. Then Ingress Controller to handle incoming traffic outside cluster through http/https.<br>

Comment: Thanks Yvan! After some more time with Kubernetes we managed to make use of it more or less as you said.

For our custom load balancing / proxy logic we decided and checked API Gateway project (Spring) which happens do the proxy and forwarding for us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more time with Kubernetes I managed to make use of headless services and custom proxy but not fully implemented by myself :)

For our custom load balancing / proxy logic we decided and checked API Gateway project (Spring) which happens do the proxy and forwarding for us! Only thing we configure is the dynamic routes. Example:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator workerRoutingService(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        var routes = builder.routes();

        routes.route(r -> r
                .path("/api/worker/{resourceId}")
                .filters(f -> f.changeRequestUri(exchange -> {
                    String resourceId = ServerWebExchangeUtils.getUriTemplateVariables(exchange).get("resourceId");
                    return workerService.getWorkerEndpointByResource(resourceId);
                }))
                .uri("http://fallback/")
        );


        return routes.build();
    }
```